Is obeying this one law entirely sufficient for repentance?
Galatians 5:14 NRSV
For the whole law is summed up in a single commandment, 
‘You shall love your neighbour as yourself.’
It seems that this verse is translated the same
way across every translation. https://biblehub.com/galatians/5-14.htm

The law quoted in the question is actually the law of God (in the Ten Commandments) and quoted by Jesus as inextricably linked to the first of them, to love God utterly. Yet the New Testament speaks of all of that law as being "given by Moses". We understand in what sense; elsewhere it speaks of that law as transmitted by angels. None of that contradicts anything. Christians are clearly to heed loving God utterly in conjunction with loving one's neighbour as ones-self.
But the verse I mentioned about Moses says something interesting about Christians regarding that law: "For the law was given by Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus Christ" John 1:17 A.V. Here Christ is being compared with Moses; law is being contrasted with grace and truth via Christ. Go now to where the resurrected, incorruptible Christ is written about:

"And by him all that believe are justified from all things, from which
ye could not be justified by the law of Moses." "Therefore by the deeds of the law there shall be no flesh be justified in his sight: for by the law is the knowledge of sin." Acts 13:38-39 & Romans 3:20 A.V.
"If ye fulfil the royal law according to the scripture, 'Thou shalt
love thy neighbour as thyself', ye do well: But if ye have respect to
persons, ye commit sin, and are convinced of the law as transgressors.
For whoever shall keep the whole law, and yet offend in one point, he
is guilty of all." James 2:8-10 A.V.

Yes, "For all the law is fulfilled in one word, in this; 'Thou shalt love thy neighbour as thyself'- Galatians 5:14 - but doing what we ought to do neither brings us to repentance nor justifies us in the sight of God. But, anyway, not a soul ever keeps that law perfectly, because we are all sinners, and God's perfect law only condemns us as law-breakers. That is why Christ had to come, to fulfil the law, so that - by the sinless one bearing sin in  his body in sacrifice, the law would no longer condemn us:

"Blotting out the handwriting of ordinances that was against us, which
was contrary to us, and took it out of the way, nailing it to the
cross" - Colossians 2:14 A.V. & 1 Peter 2:24

Repentance for sin comes first, then we are enabled to love God, and our neighbour, as we should, without condemnation when we inevitably fail in both respects, on occasion. True repentance delivers from condemnation. It has to come first. We do well to love our neighbour, but that will not, in itself, lead to repentance that saves us from the righteous wrath of God. After all, lots of atheists and secular humanists can appear to show great love to their neighbours, but they have no regard for keeping the first command that enables that part to be carried out - to love God utterly.

Very nice answer, Anne. +1  I would argue that changing our minds about sinning comes after having faith in Christ, with the understanding that it is why Christ died on the cross (when God stopped imputing the world's sins). I would agree that we change our minds, at some point prior to salvation, about our need of a savior...yes, from our sins, but removing sin from our lives comes from the love we see in God's grace, as is displayed on the cross.  We realize that we need God, we see that God gave us Christ for our sins, we believe this unto salvation, we then work for God from this truth.

@MarkVestal  Appreciated. The Q asked what would be sufficient for repentance, and I wonder if the idea behind it is that keeping that one law would suffice to 'count' as repentance? I may be wrong, but I deliberately did not deal with much that you mention to show that no amount of law-keeping saves anyone, as no-one can perfectly keep God's perfect law.  I know that we must live by faith of Christ Jesus Gal.2:20 but this seems to ask if one special law will 'count' as acceptable repentance.

I see. I believe this is why it is important to recognize the differences in what Peter says to "ye men of Israel", compared to what Paul says to us Gentiles.  With the exception of repentance toward God (changing our mind about needing Him), any level of repentance (as in changing our minds about sinning), would then fall on how well we did that, thus placing salvation on our own merits...which, as Paul states to us, negates the free gift of salvation being by God's grace through having faith alone.  Israel must still "endure unto the end", but we are offered salvation TODAY, by having faith.

Repentance
Let's look at Acts 3:17 - 19

17 “And now, brothers, I know that you acted in ignorance, as did also your rulers. 18 But what God foretold by the mouth of all the prophets, that his Christ would suffer, he thus fulfilled. 19 Repent therefore, and turn back, that your sins may be blotted out,

The word "repent" in verse 19 is "metanoeō" meaning to change one's mind, to think differently, to turn away from rebellion against God and toward obedience.
Following God's law does not bring repentance. Following God's law is an indicator that repentance has happened. When a person repents that person recognizes that they are acting against God and they turn from their own way to God's way.
Romans 3:21 - 24 tells us that everyone breaks the law (v23) and that justification (a restored relationship with God) is a gift of God through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus (v24)

21 But now the righteousness of God has been manifested apart from the law, although the Law and the Prophets bear witness to it— 22 the righteousness of God through faith in Jesus Christ for all who believe. For there is no distinction: 23 for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God, 24 and are justified by his grace as a gift, through the redemption that is in Christ Jesus,

When repentance is followed by trusting (faith) in Jesus, believing in Jesus' death on the cross to pay for everyone's sin and Jesus' resurrection demonstrating his victory over death then that person is redeemed - brought into right relationship with God.
Paul goes on to say in chapter 3:

28 For we hold that one is justified by faith apart from works of the law. 29 Or is God the God of Jews only? Is he not the God of Gentiles also? Yes, of Gentiles also, 30 since God is one—who will justify the circumcised by faith and the uncircumcised through faith. 31 Do we then overthrow the law by this faith? By no means! On the contrary, we uphold the law.

Justification - a right relationship with God - is by faith, not by works - such as following the law (v28).
The law is upheld by the faithful as a result of that faith (v31)
Summarizing the Law
Galatians 5:14 sums up the law as far as how we treat each other is concerned.
Looking at the context:
Galatians 5:13-15

13 For you were called to freedom, brothers. Only do not use your freedom as an opportunity for the flesh, but through love serve one another. 14 For the whole law is fulfilled in one word: “You shall love your neighbor as yourself.” 15 But if you bite and devour one another, watch out that you are not consumed by one another.

The author is talking about how Christians should treat one another.
A complete summary of the law is found in:
Mark 12:29-31

29 Jesus answered, “The most important is, ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one. 30 And you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’ 31 The second is this: ‘You shall love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no other commandment greater than these.”

Matthew 22:37-40

37 And he said to him, “You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind. 38 This is the great and first commandment. 39 And a second is like it: You shall love your neighbor as yourself. 40 On these two commandments depend all the Law and the Prophets.”

and in Luke 10:27-28

27 And he answered, “You shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength and with all your mind, and your neighbor as yourself.” 28 And he said to him, “You have answered correctly; do this, and you will live.”


So we can safely ignore every other law (that is not already included in these two) everywhere else?

@polcott You mean like traffic laws, tax laws, etc.? Part of loving God is being subject to governing authorities. Romans 13 "1 Let every person be subject to the governing authorities. For there is no authority except from God, and those that exist have been instituted by God. 2 Therefore whoever resists the authorities resists what God has appointed, and those who resist will incur judgment."

Look at these: https://www.abc.net.au/reslib/201407/r1308729_17984331.pdf  and  https://www.cai.org/bible-studies/1050-new-testament-commands  and  https://www.facebook.com/notes/the-real-truth-movement/the-1050-new-testament-commandmentslaws/690826194404882/  and  http://www.wholebible.com/NT_commandments.htm  and  http://www.biblicalresearchreports.com/gods-commands-in-the-new-testament/

My friend's father was drafted into the Nazi army and ordered to murder someone and rightfully disobeyed this order.

@polcott You are right, there is a time to respectfully disobey - God's law is above all - Acts 4 - 18 So they called them and charged them not to speak or teach at all in the name of Jesus. 19 But Peter and John answered them, “Whether it is right in the sight of God to listen to you rather than to God, you must judge, 20 for we cannot but speak of what we have seen and heard.” - Peter respectfully refused to obey the authorities.

@Dottard Your links seem to indicate that there are many laws in the New Testament - is that your point?

@DavidD - I was trying to dispel the notion that the NT has no laws - there are more laws in the NT than in the OT.
